# Birkas Hamazon if I left the place I ate in

Tags: halacha, bentching, hamotzi-beracha

If a person washed and ate bread without the intention of completing the meal elsewhere and then left his house and cannot return, is that person allowed to say the grace after meal at his new location without eating another kezayis? If eating something is necessary, must it be food that requires a hamotzi blessing before eating, or can a mezonos suffice?

Comment: See Mishna Berakhot 8:7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless there’s great need you are obligated to return and bench even if you left unintentionally. If you already benched elsewhere bedieved it’s ok. If you don’t have bread and you can’t return (great need) you bench there, if you have bread you eat some hamotzi even if it’s less than a kezais and bench. Don’t say a brocho on the bread once again because of safek brochos lehakel (we are choshesh to the Rosh who holds that since you’re obligated to return you’re meal hasn’t ended in a case of a hamotzi). If you are Sefaradi you do say a brocho again.

Sh”A 184:1,:2, Mishnah Brurah 184:5,:7.

Comment: Consider reading this: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1607/15256

Answer (score 0):

Beit Shammai (Berachot 51b) said that if one forgot to bentch at the end of the meal and remembered when he was in a different place, he is required to return to bentch in the original place. Beit Hillel says that he is permitted to bentch where he remembered. The gemara (ibid. 53b) says that if he purposely left the place of eating without bentching, Beit Hillel agrees that he must return.

The Shulchan Aruch (Orach Chayim 184:1) cites two opinions among the Rishonim whether we accept Beit Shammai’s or Beit Hillel’s ruling regarding returning after forgetting to bentch and does not give a clear indication of which opinion he accepts.

The Mishna Berura (184: 6,7) says that one should return if it is not difficult, and that in any case, it is better to return if he is willing to. If one has bread in the new place and is willing to eat even a small amount of it, he need not return to bentch the original place, as the new place is also a place of eating (Shulchan Aruch ibid. 2).